# How do I point to a local elixir version in mix.exs file?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I have a phoenix project I'm using as a test app of sorts.  If I want to use a local version of elixir source code that I'm using (and making changes on), how do I tell phoenix to use it?  I also want to be able to use "iex -S mix" with it.  The below `elixir: ["~> 1.6.0-dev", path: '/my/local/path/to/elixir']` does not work, but it's what I'm trying to do.

I already tried adding the below and I get a syntax error.  Adding elixir to the dependencies (in the `def deps` function) didn't seem to do anything. I'm also using kiex and kerl for elixir version configuration.

```
defmodule PhoenixTestApp.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :phoenix_testbed,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: ["~> 1.6.0-dev", path: '/my/local/path/to/elixir']
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end
  ## some more default config code generated by Phoenix
  # :
  # :
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the local elixir binary.

For example, instead of `iex -S mix phx.server`, do `$YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH/bin/iex -S mix phx.server`. Other stuff like `mix`, `elixir` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is being run by `elixir`/`iex` already, so there is a chicken-egg problem trying to set an `elixir`/`iex` version from inside `mix.exs` file.

It’s more the property of the operating system, rather than the project, to select an environment. There are many different `elixir`/`erlang` version managers out in the wild. I would name (amongst others);

- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf
- https://github.com/taylor/kiex
- https://github.com/mururu/exenv

I personally use the latter and I am happy with it. It allows setting a local version per project (with local `.exenv` file,) a global version, and the easy switch between different versions.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!