# How do I modify the elixir source code and test it out locally with mix in a phoenix repo or other Elixir application?

Tags: elixir

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405710/how-do-i-point-to-a-local-elixir-version-in-mix-exs-file/45407351#45407351), I can point to a local git clone of elixir using a command using something like `$YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH/bin/iex -S mix`.  But say I modify Kernel#length in the Kernel module to print out "hello" before computing the length of a list.

When I boot up `$YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH/bin/iex -S mix`, and do `length([1,2])`, "hello" is not printed. This is after I have compiled elixir again in the *$YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH* with a command like  `bin/elixirc lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex -o lib/elixir/ebin` as posted in the Elixir readme.

So how do I make changes to the Elixir source code and test out my changes using "iex -S mix" ?

Comment: `Kernel` is kinda special. I believe you should `cd $YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH && make`, `bin/elixirc` would not compile erlang code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to make sure all the "test" binaries for Elixir occur first in your shell's $PATH variable.

```
env PATH=$YOUR_LOCAL_ELIXIR_PATH/bin:$PATH /bin/bash
```

for example. Once you've started the shell, test that you have the correct setup using:

```
which elixirc
```